# Task instance details is not view on UI

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

With following up a tutorial of the Airflow, I can't view the "task instance details".

So, how to configure it shows up? (Want to see the execution logs.)

My Airflow version is `2.5.2`, with python `3.8`.

If you need more information, please tell me.

Thanks.

---

Here is my view : each task doesn't have small rectangular icon.

[image]

---

And here is expected view :

[image]